# How to ignore dependency check in makefile

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I'd like to ignore dependency check in makefile.
For example, please look this code.

```
test:: test1 test2
    @echo "test"

test1:: back3
    @echo "test1"

test2:: back3
    @echo "test2"

back3::
    @echo "back3"
```

Results of "make test"

```
back3
test1
test2
test
```

But I want to get below result.

```
back3
test1
back3  <---- I want to run back3 again.
test2
test
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If the dependence is newest, it will not compile again except you delete or modify it everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [use Make recursively](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion):

```
test: test1 test2
    @echo "test"

test1:
    $(MAKE) back3
    @echo "test1"

test2:
    $(MAKE) back3
    @echo "test2"

back3:
    @echo "back3"
```

or use a ["canned recipe"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes):

```
define run_back3
@echo "back3"
endef

test: test1 test2
    @echo "test"

test1:
    $(run_back3)
    @echo "test1"

test2:
    $(run_back3)
    @echo "test2"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, @Jason_AnN?  I would expect the recursive make alternative, as presented in this answer, to reliably execute `echo test3` twice as part of building target `test`.  Moreover, the recursive alternative is more general than the custom function alternative, as the latter is specific to GNU make.

Comment: @Jason_AnN: Or even once. I am, of course, assuming a few things; for example, that the makefile is named something like "Makefile" and not "grimalkin". Have I missed a more plausible failure case?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Good point about the second solution being specific to GNUMake. I tend to think of GNUMake as the default, and forget that POSIX differs from it. (Personally I think that GNUMake is superior, and so much more widely used that the IEEE really ought to adopt it as the standard.)

Comment: I think GNU's is a great `make` implementation, and some of its extensions are real conveniences, but one must pay careful attention to one's compatibility requirements.  My biggest beef with it is not with the software itself but with some of its users: I see some horrendous piles of GNU extensions arising from people trying to write makefiles as if they were imperative programs.  I hate that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Do you know of a versatile, widely-used language in which people *haven't* written Big Balls of Mud? Look on the bright side; just imagine how much less employable you'd be, if everyone were a skilled engineer.

Comment: Thank you for all.
May I have to close this question? (I'm newbie so...)

Comment: @lecos: There is no need to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You write

> I'd like to ignore dependency check in makefile.

, by which you seem to mean that you want all the prerequisites of each target to be rebuilt prior to building that target, specifically *for* that target, such that prerequisites may be built more than once.

`make` simply does not work like that.  On each run, `make` builds each target at most once.  Prerequisite lists help it determine which targets need to be built, in which order, but designating a prerequisite should not be viewed as calling a subroutine.

If indeed you want something that works like calling a subroutine, then it needs to be expressed in the rule's recipe, not its prerequisite list.  Your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63133598/2402272) presents two alternatives for that. Of those, the recursive make example is more general; the one based on defining a custom function is specific to GNU `make`.